# xargs 4.2.20 of gnuwin32 silently fails on win7

Tags: cmd, xargs, gnuwin32

I am talking about xargs.exe of the findutils package from the gnuwin32  project.

When I create a pipe on windows command shell, cmd.exe, it does not run properly on windows 7 but it runs fine on windows XP:

```
dir /on /b | xargs.exe do-something.bat {}
```

Here it fails after the second line (a filename) read from standard input.
do-soemthing.bat is a rather long-running batch script. 
The file list comes from a network drive mounted on drive S: or so.

Any ideas?

Quoting from memory, I am using xargs.exe 4.2.20.1934 from 2005, it is the newest release presumably

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem when only installing the findutils package on a Windows 7 machine; installing the whole gnuwin32 and going through the installation procedure as described in the readme.txt solved it (xargs.exe is still from the same date, though).